# VBA Excel find a file (partial file name) in a set of folders

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2010, vba

Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening,

I would like some syntax help for the following code or point me in the direction of something that does it better as there is a few things that are not quite right.

I originally had a list files in a folder macro and I've adapted that to try and do what I want.

So here goes, I have a list of stem file names (strDesignDocs) and I have a top folder of where I will find a version of these files (combobox21.value).

I feed the top folder path and the part file name into the ListMyFiles function hoping that just for test purposes it will give me the message of the full file name that has been found and also the full folder path as well. it does print the message within the function but would like it to pass it back to the calling function to eventually do something else with.

With the code below:

1. it doesn't seem to exit the function once the file has been found, (it just seems to move to the next folder still looking for the same file without banging out of the entire function)
2. It doesn't return the value back to the calling function, probably because it carries on past the exit function that I still can't fix.
3. It never seems to return to the calling function but still tries to process all the files, so can only assume that it does.

TYIA

Andy

```
Dim iRow
Dim Counter
Dim myFile As Scripting.File
Sub ListFiles()
    Dim WS1, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim strDesignDocs As Variant
    On Error Resume Next

    Set WS1 = Sheets("Data")
    Set WS2 = Sheets("Clean_Up")

    With WS1
        Set strDesignDocs = .Range(.Cells(15, 1), .Cells(27, 1))
    End With

    For Each cell In strDesignDocs
        strReturnValue = ListMyFiles(ComboBox21.Value, True, cell.Value)
        Debug.Print strReturnValue
    Next
End Sub

Function ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders, sFileName)
    Dim MyObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject

    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)

    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        If InStr(1, myFile.Name, sFileName) <> 0 Then
            strReport = myFile.Name & " in " & myFile.Path
            ListMyFiles = strReport
            'Debug.Print strReport
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True, sFileName)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: to fix the issue of it not returning anything you need to declare the Function Return: `Function ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders, sFileName) as String`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman cheers for the reply but still doesn't pass back the string

Comment: have you actually stepped through the code line by line to debug and see what it's actually doing? if not, do that, and I bet you will find the reason it's not returning anything.

Comment: yep still the same, i've given up trying to make this work